# Pandas multiple dtype at import

Tags: python, pandas

How can I specify dtypes for each column when doing `pd.DataFrame(data)`? The documentation says `Only a single dtype is allowed.` but I have multiple columns with different types.

How can I do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ag, dtype={'float_col': float, "int_col": int, "other": object})
```

Without getting this error?

> TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: What is the type of `ag`?

Comment: Many different columns with different types: floats, integers and string

Comment: Could you call the dataframe without specifying data types and then post `df.head()` and `df.dtypes`?

Comment: It is already a dataframe?

Comment: No, it's a Django QuerySet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ag).astype({'float_col': float, "int_col": int, "other": object})
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
float_col    float64
int_col        int32
other         object
dtype: object
```

As opposed to `pandas.DataFrame`, `astype` **can** handle *dict or column name -> data type*.